# Simple Nginx server on docker returns 503

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm just starting up with Docker and the first example that I was trying to run already fails:

```
docker container run -p 80:80 nginx
```

The command successfully fetches the nginx/latest image from the Docker Hub registry and runs the new container, there is no indication in CMD of anything going wrong. When I browse to localhost:80 I get 503 (Service Unavailable). I'm doing this test on Windows 7.

I tried the same command on another computer (this time on macOS) and it worked as expected, no issues.

What might be a problem? I found some issues on SO similar to mine, but they were connected with the usage of nginx-proxy, which I don't use and don't even know what it is. I'm trying to run a normal http server.

//EDIT
When I try to bind my container to a different port, for example:

```
docker container run -p 4201:80 nginx
```

I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Chrome, so basically connection can't be established, because destination does not exist. Why is that?

Comment: try `docker ps` and see whether the container is running or not. Also can you paste the url which you are hitting from chrome to access the nginx?

Comment: @Yug Singh I found the reason! On Windows the IP where the result can be accessed is different than localhost address. Docker provides the correct URL at the top of the console, I didn't see that before. On macOS the address is just localhost. I wonder why on Windows they did it differently.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it didn't work is that on Windows, Docker publishes results on different IP than localhost. This IP given is at the top in Docker client console.